# Query drive free space

Tags: ubuntu

I have 2 1TB drives mounted to /Drives/General1 & /Drives/General2 respecitively on Ubuntu Server (my primary installation is on a 250GB). Using the terminal (I access via SSH) how do I query how much space is used/free on each drive?

I have used `fdisk -l` but this just seems to tell me the size of the drives in total and not how much is free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this command:

```
df -h
```

it wont let me post unless i have 30 chars...